# sorting elasticsearch top hits results

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to execute a query in elasticsearch to get reuslt of specific users from certain date range. the results should be grouped by userId and sorted on trackTime field, I am able to use group by using aggregation but i am not able to sort aggregation buckets on tracktime, i write down the following query

```
GET _search
{
"size": 0,
"query": {
    "filtered": {
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "must": [
                    {
                        "range": {
                            "trackTime": {
                                "from": "2016-02-08T05:51:02.000Z"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "filter": {
            "terms": {
                "userId": [
                    9,
                    10,
                    3
                ]
            }
        }
    }
},
"aggs": {
    "by_district": {
        "terms": {
            "field": "userId"
        },
        "aggs": {
            "tops": {
                "top_hits": {
                    "size": 2
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
 }
```

what more should i have to use to sort the top hits result? Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `sort` like .

```
"aggs": {
"by_district": {
    "terms": {
        "field": "userId"
    },
    "aggs": {
        "tops": {
            "top_hits": {
                "sort": [
                    {
                        "fieldName": {
                            "order": "desc"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "size": 2
            }
        }
        }
     }
 }
```

Hope it  helps

Comment: @Richa  I am in similar scenario. My fieldname for Sort under Top_hits aggregation is like 2 levels deeper. for eg: "sort":{"user.name.fieldName":{"order":"desc"}}.. its not working in such scenario. any thoughts..?

Comment: @Arivazhagan Jeganathan: It is working for me.Is the type of user `nested`?

Comment: @Richa Its kind of nested. But do not have array or multiple values associated. Hope I am clear.

Comment: If its nested, you can read this link https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-sorting.html