# Unable to sort aggregation bucket results in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I am trying to execute a query in elasticsearch to get a list of products with the largest sales change percentage. The aggregation results should be group by *productId* and sorted by *salesChangePercent*. I have search around for a solution and tried solutions such as [sorting elasticsearch top hits results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35331088/sorting-elasticsearch-top-hits-results) but I am not able to sort the aggregation buckets by *salesChangePercent*. The following query is the only one which work, however it does not seem right to me as I am using "max_salesChangePercent" to do the sorting.

Am I doing something wrong here? Is there a better or cleaner way to get the aggregation buckets sorted? Really appreciate any help I can get to improve the query.

```
GET product_sales/_search {
    “size”: 0,
    “query”: {
        “range”: {
            “salesChangePercent”: { “gte”: 50 }
        } 
    },
    “aggs”: {
        “unique_products”: {
            “terms”: {
                “field”: “productId”,
                “order" : {
                    “max_salesChangePercent”: “desc”
                }
            },
            “aggs”: {
                “top-sales”: {
                    “top_hits”: {
                        “size”: 1,
                        “_source”: {
                            “includes”: [
                                “productId”,
                                “productName”,
                                “salesChangePercent”,
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                },
                “max_salesChangePercent”: {
                    “max”: {
                        “field”: “salesChangePercent”
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How are your top hits sorted (since you only take a single one)? If you sort them by `salesChangePercent: desc` then sorting by `max_salesChangePercent` achieves the same thing and you already have what you need.

Comment: Top hits are sorted based on the creation date, I tried adding this line "sort":[{"salesChangePercent": {"order": "desc"}}] to top hits but it yields different results from max_salesChangePercent